# How to show/not show a Reveal depending on data being returned from an AJAX source

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have to convert a system that runs an AJAX script and displays an alert if the returned data length is greater than 0 ie a message is returned. This runs on form load, and periodically thereafter via a timer. I'm trying to impliment using Foundation 5.

When I add a Reveal to the page, it displays whether there's data or not. If I use a success callback function to check the length of the returned data, how do I stop the reveal from displaying if the length is zero? I've tried the following code:

```
    $('#messageModal').foundation('reveal', 'open', {
        url: 'check_message_ajax.php',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.length == 0) {
                return false;  // also tried "return;" and  "stop;"
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('failed loading modal');
        }
    });
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.